# How to launch a new activity using pending intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

Can anyone please say how to launch a new `Activity` using `PendingIntent` and also to pass a value using pending intent.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityToLaunch.class);
intent.putExtra(<oneOfThePutExtraFunctions>);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

You can add extra data into an Intent by using one of the various Intent.PutExtra() functions located: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Then, when you are ready to launch your PendingIntent, use one of the Send() functions located: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: The documentation of `PendingIntent.getActivity` says "Note that the activity will be started outside of the context of an existing activity, so you must use the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK launch flag in the Intent". So you probably should do `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`.

Comment: Starting 31, S, you need to specify PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE like PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(requireActivity(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);