# Determine if PendingIntent is an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-pendingintent

Is there a way to tell if `PendingIntent` or `IntentSender` will launch an activity (as opposed to a broadcast or service)?

`PendingIntent` has an [`isActivity()`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/PendingIntent.java#L1004) function, but it's marked as `@hide`.

I have tried to copy/paste the code in from [here](https://github.com/ChameleonOS/miui_framework/blob/master/java/android/app/ActivityManagerProxy.java)  but to no avail.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this, but reflection might be way to go here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/880365/794088

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896672/how-to-launch-a-new-activity-using-pending-intent

Comment: for what purpose? are you trying to distinguish between `PendingIntent` internal to your application?

Comment: We are given PendingIntents by the NotificationListenerService and trying to figure out which will launch apps and which will not. For instance, "Like" on a Facebook notification will not launch the app, whereas hitting "reply" on Gmail will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `PendingIntent` is just a reference to the actual `Intent`. The `PendingIntent` doesn't actually contain any of the data, so you cannot look at it. The actual `Intent` is managed by Android itself. There's unfortunately no way you can get the information you want.

**NOTE: The above answer is not correct. Starting with Android 4.1, it is possible to determine if the `Intent` wrapped by a `PendingIntent` will launch an `Activity`.**

You can do it using reflection, like this:

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = ... // This is the `PendingIntent`
    try {
        Method method = PendingIntent.class.getDeclaredMethod("isActivity");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Boolean isActivity = m.invoke(pendingIntent);
        if (isActivity) {
            // PendingIntent will launch an Activity
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Problem using reflection
    }
```

On versions of Android older than 4.1 this will throw a `NoSuchMethodException`.

Calling the (private) method `isActivity()` on the `PendingIntent` generates a call to the Android `ActivityManager`, asking it if the target of the `PendingIntent` is an `Activity`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Thank you so much for your comment. I love being proved wrong. And I have learned something new today. I was looking at an older version of the Android source code where this method does not exist! `isActivity()` is available from Android 4.1. In older versions the method does not exist. I really appreciate this.

Comment: you might want to remove the first paragraph. Some people stop reading when they think they have the answer

Comment: @TimCastelijns I thought about that, but then the comment thread makes no sense. Part of the first paragraph is actually correct, in that the `PendingIntent` really doesn't have this information. The `isActivity()` method has to go ask the `ActivityManager` for the answer. I'm open to suggestions about how to improve the answer, but I don't think removing the original answer it the best way to do it.